Add a List of Document References into a flutter/firebase document field
I got this code:
  var testList = <String>[];

  await db
      .collection('tests')
      .where('user', arrayContainsAny: [db.doc('users/' + uid)])
      .get()
      .then((value) {
        value.docs.forEach((element) {
          testList.add(element.id);
        });
      });

  for (final test in testList) {
    print(test);
  }

this runs smoothly and i get a testList of 2 test ids. Later i am trying this:
        final testCollectionEntries = {
          'tests': db.doc('tests/' + testList),
          'name': testCollectionName
        };

        await db.collection("testsCollection").add(testCollectionEntries );

tests is a field type of a List of Document References in firebase. How can i make a list of Document References in order to use it to this code.

db.doc only creates a single document reference.  I suspect you're going to have to call it once for each reference you want to create, then put all those references into a list, then provide that list to Firestore.

i got a list of ids as testList. How can i convert it to document reference list?

I found this as an answer. You need to make your code like this instead:
final testCollectionEntries = {
    //'tests': db.doc('tests/' + testList), //REMOVE THIS IN ORDER TO USE UPDATE LATER
    'name': testCollectionName
    };
       
DocumentReference testRef = //ADD THIS VAR
   await db.collection("testsCollection").add(testCollectionEntries);

await db
    .collection('test')
    .where('user', arrayContainsAny: [db.doc('users/' + uid)])
    .get()
    .then((value) {  //USE THEN FOR ITERATION
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        print(db.doc('tests/' + element.id));
        testRef.update({
          'examinerList':
              FieldValue.arrayUnion([db.doc('examiners/' + element.id)]) //DONT FORGET BRACKETS []
        });
      });
    });

